# Bootstrap Modal Pop up is not working in asp .net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Am trying to follow this tutorial
http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/0f1b65c3-b0f6-4a93-b4b5-56c278d855c2/Editable%20Grid%20View%20System%20us#.VXqaM_mqqko

but pop is not displaying in my project only difference is am using master page in my project is that the issue ??

please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Check if you have the necessary `js` file(s). Also use the developer console in the browser to see if you've got any errors

Comment: Have you checked that jQuery has been loaded? Please post some code so we can help further.

Comment: this error am getting in console  window   TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
<script type='text/javascript'>$('#deleteModal').modal('show');</script> am using this in code behind

Comment: @KeerthiKumar It means that you haven't include `bootstrap.js` file into your solution. Check your HTML source. Is `bootstrap.js` there? Is it a correct path? If it is not - add this and it will work.

Comment: thin is my content template id <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<link href="../Resources/CSS/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="../Resources/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="../Resources/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>

Comment: ya it is present in source

Comment: No i have resolved that conflict but still it is not displaying popup

Comment: Have you tried moving the JQuery script before the bootstrap script? The order of the include is very important.